# Выбрать все записи A которые не имеют связанных с ними записей в B

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы A и В связанные отношением один ко многим соответственно.

Необходимо выбрать все записи A которые не имеют связанных с ними записей в B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN вам в помощь. Вероятно, вот такой:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableA.id IS null OR TableB.id IS null

id    name       id    name
--    ----       --    ----
2     Monkey     null  null
4     Spaghetti  null  null
null  null       1     Rutabaga
```

null  null       3     Darth Vader

Comment: А так не проще ? :)

    SELECT * FROM A where id_from_a not in (select id_from_a from В)